# Evaluation of annotation

Tags: natural-language-processing, computational-linguistics

I'm doing a research on NLG systems. 
I need to annotate my corpus (~6 million words) automatically. My algorithm works well and I want to calculate [Cohen's Kappa](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch10.html#sec:eval:kappa). What I cannot understand is the second annotator; I don't have the possibility to have another annotation. 
Is there any solution for this problem? Can I have a set of data as my sample and manually doing the annotation to calculate Cohen's Kappa? Is there any measurement for corpus analysis?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What's a NLG system?  (It might help to spell out the acronym.)  Annotate your corpus with what?  Why do you want to compute Cohen's kappa?  Cohen's kappa is only relevant if you have two independent annotations; if you don't, then it's irrelevant, so I'm not sure why you want to compute it.  What are you trying to achieve?  What's your real end goal?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!